# Safari blocks CORS request to Express API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, safari, cors

I have a simple node/express server which I use as an API for my AngularJS app. It's running at `localhost:8080`

```
let express = require('express');
...

let cors    = require('cors');
...

let app     = express();
app.use(cors());

let port    = Number(process.env.PORT || 8080);
...

app.use('/api', require('./routes'));
app.use('*', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(httpStatus[404]).end());

app.listen(port, () => logger.info("✔ Listening on port " + port));
```

Pretty basic stuff. `cors()` should be allowing requests from any origin with the methods `GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE`.

My Angular app at `localhost:3000` simply makes a `GET` request to my server, which runs fine on Firefox and Chrome, but gives me the following on Safari only:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/drawings/all. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I thought that CORS was handled entirely by the server, and that there shouldn't be cross-browser problems. I've read that Safari is stricter in this regard, but I want to make sure that my users don't have to change something in their preferences in order to get the site to work. Even in the developer console on Safari, checking "Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions" does nothing to help me.

My server logs the request, and returns a `200` status.

Comment: Clear your cache?  Looks like Safari may have a problem according to https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1355

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the CORS issue, but now I have a weird angularJS error I haven't encountered in the other browsers. I'll start another question.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing Safari's cache solved this problem.